# how to iterate through one column matrix in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, loops, matrix

I'm new to MATLAB and i'm trying to figure out how I would iterate over a matrix with only one column to count the occurrence of some number, n. For example, I would like to count how many times '1' appears in the matrix:
1
4
1
88
6
22
1

How could I make a loop that returns '3'? How would I create a loop that counts how many times some loop counter occurs (i.e. start at 0 and increment by one each loop to count how many times the counter occurs in the matrix)?

Thanks

Comment: Ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 5):

Just use **[`sum`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/sum.html)**

```
>> a=[1 4 1 88 6 22 1]';
>> n=1;
>> sum(a==n)

ans =

     3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1 4 1 88 6 22 1];
count_n = size(a(a==n));
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need to run a loop. You could just do it like this:

```
a = [ 1 4 1 88 6 22 1];
n = 1;
length(find(a(:)==n))
```